# Python - equivalence of calling function with key-value arguments

Tags: python

Let's consider
`foo(arg1=123, arg2=None)` and `foo(arg1=123)`.
Tell me please, if these two ways are equivalent ?

Comment: Hint: *Why* do you think they are equivalent?

Comment: Do you want [overloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30693266/1015062) function?

Comment: @heemayl because in case of `foo(arg1=123)` we have also that `arg2=None`. Yeah ?

Comment: I've  added an answer.

Comment: @newbie Only if `def foo(arg1, arg2=None)`. There is no implicit default value; if `foo` is defined as `def foo(arg1, arg2)`, then `foo(arg1=123)` is an error, because you didn't provide a value for the required argument `arg2`.

Comment: If those are definitions, then they are clearly not equivalent. If those are *calls*, then whether they are equivalent  depends on how `foo` was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the two given function signatures (and hence functions) are not equivalent.

In `foo(arg1=123, arg2=None)`, you have two arguments -- `arg1` and `arg2`, which can be used inside the function as local names. Note that, assigning a value of `None` to some name does not make it anything special/different as far as the assignment statements are concerned. It is in fact a common way to give a placeholder value for a variable that is not mandatory or may be an empty mutable object.

On the other hand, `foo(arg1=123)` has only one argument `arg1`, which is available on the function's local scope for use.

---

**Edit:**

If you have a function defined as `foo(arg1, arg2)`, both arguments are mandatory (positional) arguments.

So, `foo(arg1=21)` will throw a `TypeError` as you have not provided `arg2`. Whereas, `foo(arg1=21, arg2=None)` will work just fine as you have provided values for both the arguments.

---

**Edit2:**

If you have a function defined as `foo(arg1=None, arg2=None)` (or something similar i.e. with default values), both arguments are optional (keyword) arguments. In that case, both of the mentioned definitions would be the same.

Comment: I meant something differ. We have function: `foo(arg1, arg2)`. Now, the question is: Are there equivalent two **calls**:  `foo(arg1=21)` and `foo(arg1=21, arg2=None)`.

Comment: thanks for your involvment. Can you give some another example when these two calls will be equivalent ?

Comment: @newbie These two calls will never be equivalent. Now, i'm not sure what are you getting at.

Comment: You used term: `mandatory (positional) `. What about situation when these arguments are not mandatory ?